# Laravel one-to-many save Carbon error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I have a class called SubjectData:

```
class SubjectData extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'subject_datas';

    protected $fillable = ['firstname','lastname','birthdate','birthcity','months'];

    protected $dates = ['birthdate'];

    public function setBirthdateAttribute($date) 
    {
        // So we can add the time, not just he php date
        $this->attributes['birthdate'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
    }

    public function anamnesis() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Anamnesis');
    }
}
```

And I have a class called Anamnesis:

```
class Anamnesis extends Model
{
    public function meetingTest() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\MeetingTest');
    }

    public function subject() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Subject','subject_id','id');
    }

    public function subjectData() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\SubjectData');
    }

    public function scholarHistory() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\ScholarHistory');
    }

    public function familyHistory() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\FamilyHistory');
    }

    public function psicodiagnosis() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Psicodiagnosis');
    }
}
```

The store function of the SubjectController class works like this:

```
public function store(CreateSubjectRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        // Let's generate the anamnesis of the subject
        $anamnesis = Anamnesis::create();
        $anamnesis->save();

        $newSubjectData = $this->saveSubjectData($input);  
        $anamnesis->subjectData()->save($newSubjectData);
        ......
        ......
}
```

where the function called is:

```
public function saveSubjectData($input) 
    {
        $subjectData['firstname'] = $input['firstname'];
        $subjectData['lastname'] = $input['lastname'];
        $subjectData['birthcity'] = $input['birthcity'];
        $subjectData['birthdate'] = $input['birthdate'];

        return SubjectData::create($subjectData);
    }
```

The problem is with the "birthdate" property.

If i check the value of $newSubjectData (dd($newSubjectdata)) after the call $this->saveSubjectData($input) the value of the birthdate is exactly the one i set on the calendar in the frontside (and also in the db the value is correct)

If I put the dd($anamnesis->subjectData) after the call $anamnesis->subjectData()->save($newSubjectData) the result is the "today" date and also in the DB the value is not the one I set but the date of today.

I can't find the error

P.S. The calendar is inside a Vue template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that, the date must be an instance of Carbon or is properly formatted according to your database table. Try the following inside your saveSubjectData() method

```
$subjectData['birthdate']  = Carbon\Carbon::parse($input['birthdate']
```

Comment: The fact is that until I get to the command $anamnesis->subjectData()->save($newSubjectData) the date is correctly saved in the DB. This due to the fact that I set the property to be of type  $dates inside the model. Even without make the command Carbon\Carbon:formatFrom... it works.. Only when I try to connect it to anamnesis seems to reset the date.

Comment: I see. Try this istead of using `save()` : `$anamnesis->subjectData()->attach($newSubjectData);`

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()

Comment: Sorry 'bout that I didn' t realize you're using a hasOne. Anyways, I digged through Laravel and found that the save method sets the foreign id of the model you passed in (in your case the SubjectData).  The `save()` method of the Model then updates the model attributes and that includes the timestamps. The solution, I think is to use `$anamnesis->subject_data_id = $newSubjectData->id` then save it `$anamnesis->save()`

Comment: I wrote the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I write down the answer but i thank John Aldrin that guided me in the right direction.

You have to put the timestamp('birthdate') AFTER the default timestamps of the migration table (so at the end of the migration table)

I don't know why. If someone knows please explain !

Comment: That's strange o_O I have a table named events and my migration has `$table->timestamp('wouldbe_on'); $table->timestamps(); $table->softDeletes();` Anyways, great that you've solved it yourself :)